# Mongo, Ruby, Enumerable - What am i doing wrong?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongodb-query

What am I doing wrong?

```
db = Mongo::MongoClient.new(DB_URI)
tags = db['tags'].find()
tag_ids = tags.map { |t| t['_id'] }

puts tags.count
=> 4272

tags.each do |t|
  puts t.inspect
end
=> # does not produce anything. As if it was empty.
```

If i'm comment this line 
`# tag_ids = tags.map { |t| t['_id'] }`, the each method works correctly.

using `ruby 1.9.3p545` and gem `mongo 1.9.2`

Comment: Just tell me the output of `puts db['tags'].find().class`..

Comment: In last loop you get `t`, but then puts `tag`. Try to change it to `t.inspect`

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev Put it as answer.. :-) It seems.. I am still sleeping in this afternoon. :)

Comment: @ArupRakshit it's just a misspell, don't worth any points ;)

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev Humm.. Correct.. ;)

Comment: @ArupRakshit : returns me => Mongo::Cursor

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev : yea sorry, made this mistake writing the example. But anyway, it does not returns me NameError

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `.find()` is a [cursor](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Cursor.html) not an array or list. Cursors with databases **only** ever work one way and **once** only. You already pulled all the results out, so yes it is now empty when you go to use it again.

The `.count()` method returns meta-data from the cursor that holds the number returned. So usage of that is okay

You can use the [`.rewind()`](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Cursor.html#rewind!-instance_method) method. But all this really does is execute the query again. So that may or may not be what you want.

If you need to use the list several times, then pull all the results to their own array and do you different iterations that way. Or figure a way to do what you want in "one pass".

Comment: Thanx for your answer. so i've tried to replace line 2. by  `tags = db['tags'].find().to_a` . This method called on Mongo::Cursor should execute the query and then return me an array of hashes. So i'm dealing with an Array. And it's still does not work..

Comment: Ok. Even worst : when using `map` instead of 'each' . I thought `map` used `each`..

Comment: @user3471833 `.to_a` should be working for you as per my last statement there. Try and debug the content, possibly with `.limit()` and `JSON.pretty_generate()` over the limited array in order to see that the results are what you expect.